# Locked out of remote machine when changing password

Tags: ssh, password, remote

TLDR : Not able to login after resetting the password on a remote machine. The machine is on a truck that's 1000kms away.

I have a remote ubuntu machine which is connected through a service called remote.it . RemoteIT provides SSH connection string for the remote machine and it keeps changing periodically.

I wanted to change the password of the remote machine, so i generated a random string in my Strong password chrome extension.

Copied the new password to my local terminal.

SSHed to the remote machine, used passwd command, copied and pasted the new password from my local terminal. did that for the confirm password also. Did a sudo su, pasted the password again. And then when I logged out, I am not able to login again. The old password or the new password wouldn't work.

I think I made some mistake when copying and pasting the new password. Is there anything I can do to crack the password?

Comment: I copied the password generated to a TextPad and the TextPad capitalized the first letter. Fixing that let me log in again.

Answer (score 0):

I did this years ago. After many attempts I tried a space on the end of the password. When I copied the password I accidentally copied a single white space on the end. Then pasted it into the passwd command twice. Took me a couple hours to figure out what I had done. 
If a single space doesn't work try two, three etc. or maybe space preceding the password. Copying text can get all kinds of hidden fun.

Hopefully pam.d (pam_tally2) doesn't lock your account on too many fails! Most non root accounts will reset after a period of time. Depends on how it was secured when set up. 
Root accounts do not usually lock on too many login fails but are restricted to not directly login to ssh port.
You may have to get console access or another user with credentials and root to change the PW.

Good luck.

Comment: Tried with spaces, didnt help. Trying to check what other text i would have copied.

Comment: Maybe generate another password and then copy it and paste it into a text editor that can show special chars to see if there was any  hidden baggage that comes along. 
You may just be locked with pam.d. some servers will never clear a lock until someone with root access resets the account with 
 pam_tally2 -u MyUserName -r

Comment: I don't know RemoteIT. Some applications like that have to be in sync with the user account. meaning you would usually change the password in RemoteIT too.